# Unexpected error occurred in Devart dotConnect for MySql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am using [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) tool to connect with MySql.

Now I am getting following error

[image]

I have tried to uninstall it several times but I can't uninstall it.

Any suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: try to search for registry enties using regedit command and (ctrl+F) and delete every entry associated with this tool. Once done, do uninstallation of tool.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on my computer only via manually removing corresponding keys in System Registry.
I used search by "devart" word and removed founded items.
It's not so elegant way but it helps me.....